# Why are buttons discouraged from navigation?

Tags: html, css, navigation

This may be an opinionated question, but I was looking around the web and it seems like web developers like to style `<a>` tags to look like buttons, rather than use a specific `<button>` tag. I've noticeably seen this when looking at navigations.

After a bit of research, I found this:

> - Buttons are not search friendly, since the text within is invisible to search engines.
> - Buttons are harder to update than links, requiring Photoshop and a new image for every update.
> - Buttons load more slowly than links, making them especially bad for mobile visitors.
> - Buttons are less accessible to the visually impaired.
> - Buttons are unnecessary, even if you want to use non-standard fonts, thanks to tools like TypeKit.
>   ~ quoted from [here](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/common-website-navigation-mistakes/)

However, most of these 'reasons' seem quite flimsy and answers like 'you need Photoshop' seem... well... invalid?

So I was wondering:

**Is there an actual reason why the `<button>` tags aren't used when creating navigation menus, and instead style `<a>` tags to look like buttons?**

*Why aren't buttons the norm? Is this not what they're made for?*

<sup>* I do not wish for your opinion here, nor viewpoint. Only factual information as to why this is the case</sup>

Comment: [When to Use Button](https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/)

Comment: @Paulie_D: cheers for the link. I understand that this is borderline, but I had the question, and didn't know the answer. It's just the amount of navs that style links *like* buttons was really confusing me, and hence I was looking to see if there was 'a factual reason' why developers aren't using them.

Comment: Also [w3c says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element): *"If the a element has an href attribute, then it represents a hyperlink (a hypertext anchor). If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant."*. A button on the other hand does not represent a hyperlink. As a navigation clearly consists of hyperlinks instead of just GUI elements, `a`-elements would be your choice.

Comment: @UsmanArshad thanks for your link. I think I'm starting to understand when to use one and when to use another. It seems there is a clear difference between *doSomethingforme* and *takemesomewhere*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading up on multiple documents posted in the comments, it seems that there is actually a clear **factual** reason buttons are not used in navigation bars.

## Anchor tags

These are used when there is a *page redirect* or taking a user elsewhere on the website.

> - If it navigates, it is a link. Use link markup with a valid hypertext reference
>
> ~[Links are not buttons](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

## Button elements

These are used when you want to *doSomething()* that is **not** redirecting the user. I.e. submitting a form / etc.

---

The question you need to ask yourself is:

**Will this control be used to initiate an immediate action *or* Is the action to navigate to another page?**

if the answer to your question is the first part, then you should be using a `button` element. Whereas if it is the latter that you are wishing to do, then you **should** be using an `a` element.

**further Reading:**

- [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)
- [Links are not buttons. Neither are DIVs and SPANs](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)
- [When To Use The Button Element](https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/)