# How do I show a BUTTON border outside of it's parent DIV area?

Tags: html, css, parent

I tried using box-shadow instead, I want to know if there's any easy, efficient way around this.

CSS

```
div {
text-align: left;
background: #F5F5F5;
width: 500px;
padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
margin: 10px;
}
button {
border: 0;
border-bottom: 5px 0 0 #F00;
background: #F5F5F5;
width: 100px;
padding: 10px 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
<button>test_1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just curious..why would you need this?

Comment: I'm trying to make a navigation bar for my flat-file forum. I think I would just like the way it looks.

Comment: The border will actually only be added when you hover, and if you hover over a link just before you will get a regular cursor and it wouldn't look right.

Comment: You can pick any cursor you like,it's a CSS property.

Comment: I know but this is a file I'm trying to keep as short as possible. I think it's unnecessary when there are better alternatives. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is for the button to be 5px lower than its parent `div`, you can add this CSS:

```
button {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfytswww/)

Comment: The buttons transitions before the cursors on the div using this, although it doesn't really matter I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of of browser support for pseudo-elements on `button` elements but this works in Chrome.

```css
div {
    text-align: left;
    background: #F5F5F5;
     border-bottom:1px solid grey; /* for demo only */
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
button {
    border-width:0;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

button:hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #F00;    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>test_1</button>
</div>
```

I would also point out this question on SO that is somewhat relevant.

[**Why are button's discouraged from navigation*?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936608/why-are-buttons-discouraged-from-navigation)

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved merely suppressing `border: 0;` from your CSS.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x50L2vht/), where I also set a great height for `<button>` and a little height for `<div>` to make it more obvious.