# Bootstrap Column Same Height with Button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML Code:

```html
<div class="row align-items-center" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
   <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 2px;">
      <a href="#"><button style="width: 100%;">Test</button></a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 2px;">
      <img style="width: 100%;" src="resources/assets/images/square-test.png">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 2px;">
      <img style="width: 100%;" src="resources/assets/images/square-test.png">
   <div>
</div>
```

And currently it shows like this...

[image]

What can I do for the button height?
To make sure it is always the same height as the other columns their width.
For width 100% seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, please note **Links are not allowed to have buttons as children and vice versa**

To solve your issue, just remove the `align-items-center` class, then just set the button height to 100%;

```css
.col-4 button {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
   <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 2px;">
     <button style="width: 100%;">Test</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 2px;">
      <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 2px;">
      <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196">
   <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I ended up trying out different ways but did not manage to achieve a good result. Should I use a form with a submit button to use the button as a redirect? Thank you

Comment: Also, when the columns are wrapped (i.e. on each other) - is there a way to ensure that the button column remains the same height as the other columns?

Comment: If you are submitting data use a button. If you are linking to something use a link. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936608/why-are-buttons-discouraged-from-navigation/30937223#30937223

Comment: Sure, but I would have liked the whole column to be clickable rather than just the link...

Comment: If you want a redirect just use a link instead of a `button` it should still work exactly the same with jst a few minor tweaks - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eYYzyEr

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks. How about when the columns become on top of each other... Is there a way to ensure that the height remains the same in that case? Thanks

Comment: That's something for another question.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the style that you can pass in class with `bootstrap`, try this :

```
<div class="row align-items-center m-0 p-0">
   <div class="col-4 bg-danger m-0 p-1">
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-dark w-100 h-100>Test</button></a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4 bg-danger m-0 p-1">
      <img class="w-100" src="resources/assets/images/square-test.png">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4 bg-danger m-0 p-1">
      <img class="w-100" src="resources/assets/images/square-test.png">
   <div>
</div>
```