# Is there a valid use case for styling a div as a button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Title says it all, is there ever an actual use case where you should style a `<div>`, `<span>` etc. as a button rather than just have a button?

Bootstrap still has a `.btn` class - is this backwards compatibility (to when styling buttons was difficult) or am I missing some use case that means we still need this?

**EDIT to make it clear**

Thanks for the answers and comments but I perhaps wasn't clear.

I am looking for someone to provide a valid reason that a `<div>` or , `<span>` etc. than a `<button>` and the occasional `<a>` should be styled to look like a button (thanks to @James Grimshaw for pointing it it could be valid for a `<a>` element to look like a button).

If not why doesn't bootstrap use `a.btn-block, button.btn-block` as selectors to enforce correct semantics and also save devs having to write `btn` within the class list for an element?

Comment: no, it is strictly forbidden, if you do such a thing the big mamamouchi will come to pull your ears during your sleep

Comment: if it is a matter of styling : `div {
-moz-appearace:button;  appearance: button;
  display:inline-block;
}` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: https://karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936608/why-are-buttons-discouraged-from-navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap `.btn` class is designed to be used with `a` or `button` elements. For example:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">A button</a>
```

There could be potential use cases to use a `div`, and some websites do this, since you could use the JavaScript `onclick=""` handler to detect clicks and allow it to act like a regular `button` or `a` element. However it definitely isn't recommend, and you should stick to using a standard button or link for the following reasons:

1. **If JavaScript was disabled for any reason**: Regular `button` or `a` elements have default browser behaviour, and don't require JavaScript.
2. **Accessibility**: Standard button or link elements are automatically recognised to have an action associated with them, whereas `div` or `span` elements aren't expected to have a click action.
3. **Functionality**: In the case of Bootstrap, the `.btn` class also targets `button` or `a` specific states such as `disabled`, `:focus`, or `:visited`, meaning that all aspects of the `.btn` class wouldn't even work entirely with a `div` or `span`.

Comment: The answer you gave is great except it reinforces my question rather than answering it. I have edited to reinforce what I asked (as it could be a phrasing issue) - is there a valid reason to style anything other than a button as a button? chers Graham

Comment: I guess my answer then would be no, there is a valid reason to use a div as a button (to navigate somewhere or do something), but there is no reason to style anything other than a button as a button, for the reasons above.

Comment: actually +1 for the first part as I suppose you could style an `a` as a button and it not be incorrect. But why not use `a.btn-large`, `button.button-large` if those are the only two use cases?

Comment: Flexibility. It's less code to not specify the element the class should be used with, and provides less restriction. In code you can do what you want, but best practices exist to ensure the user experience will be the best possible.

Comment: but restriction would actually be a good thing, it would enforce correct practices and make the web a better place overall. I think the point of my question more was why would there ever be a use case to use a div as a button? Sorry the question could be taken a couple of ways I see now.

Comment: This topic could really be debated, with my opinion being that there is no use case. Another point to mention is that the .btn class also targets `button` or `a` specific states such as `disabled`, `:focus`, or `:visited`, meaning that all aspects of the `.btn` class wouldn't even work entirely with a `div` or `span`.

Comment: Thanks James, I think we are on the same page, I just wanted to see if there was a valid use case and I don't think there will be. I will give the question a day or so just in case someone does come up with a valid case and if not accept your answer.

Comment: only took me three months but finally accepted, my last act of 2019!