# Using <a> instead of <button> - any instances where this is advantageous?

Tags: javascript, html, css, standards

I notice this in people's code a lot where they create a button (styled as button etc for example in a to do list) and I'll wonder why they aren't using a button tag but an a naming the class to btn/button/etc. Wondering if there are any specific reasons to do this and which is better practice?

Comment: Well, an <a> is used for links and buttons are actions.

Comment: As with all HTML tags - you need to take into account the semantic use of the tag, though [this can be rather blurry with some of them](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277778/why-are-people-making-tables-with-divs).

Comment: There are a lot of things you can do with a link that you can’t do with a button, like copy it, share it, or open it in a new tab. If link-like operations make semantic sense, you should use a link, even if you want it to look like a button. On the other hand, if you find yourself writing `<a href="#" onclick="…">` or `<a href="javascript:…">`, you should use a button instead of a link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936608/why-are-buttons-discouraged-from-navigation

Answer (score 1):

Use an `a` tag when you want to navigate to a new page or an external resource i.e. links.

Use a `button` tag to perform an action like to open a modal, delete an item, close a modal, etc.

Comment: Semantic use is the key (plus one).

Comment: Semantic use is of particular importance for accessibility. Screen readers read anchors and buttons differently, iirc.

Answer (score 0):

- a tag is used for link & navigation.
- button is for actions (form validation, add item...)