# Should I use anchor or button elements for tabbed navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, navigation

I am building a website and have previously built navigation using both buttons and anchors. I am confused which one to use for tabbed navigation.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936608/why-are-buttons-discouraged-from-navigation) question/answer which essentially came down to:

Use `<a>` when you are redirecting to another page as this is the intended use of a hyperlink.

Use `<button>` to carry out an action like a form submission, or to execute a function.

This makes a lot of sense to me, but my particular site is an app with tabbed navigation. I have a few pages that are being built by manipulating the DOM, but the site link remains the same, and the navigation is actually just replacing existing dom elements with new ones.

In this case, is it better to use buttons for navigation, or should I just always stick to anchors even if they aren't "redirecting" the page traditionally? I know that some of the differences are just subjective, such as the out of the box styling differences, but are there considerable drawbacks for using one over the other in tabbed navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically speaking, this sounds like same-page navigation to me. As per standards, use the `<a>` element for this purpose. Then add an event listener for any JavaScript side effects.

- [Read the standards of the <a> element here - on whatwg.org.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)
- [Read about the <a> element on the MDN documentation - here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a.)

Answer (score 0):

**W3C uses buttons**:

I'm a huge fan of MDN as well, however, `<button>` is used in the [How to create tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) example.

**My personal understanding**

It feels like there is some legal choice to implement it, I personally look at tab and see `<nav>` and `<section>` elements assembled. As my UI framework has both of the ingridients I'm using those, the nav has a `<a>` inside (as not multi level, no need of `<ul><li>` inside...

**Additional advice for tabs creators**

However don't forget to add the `role` and `aria-*` tags, then at least it becomes clear what the intended function of the chosen element is, including accessibility support (e.g. screen readers):

..and let's use a [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tab_role#example) this time (but the code here is adapted to not overusing 'div', I like semantics:

```html
<section>
   <nav role="tablist">
      <a
         href='#'
         role="tab"
         aria-controls="panel-1"
         aria-selected="true"
         tabindex="0"
         aria-label="Tab 1"
         aria-controls="panel-1"
     >Tab 2</a>
      <a
         href='#'
         role="tab"
         aria-controls="panel-2"
         aria-selected="true"
         tabindex="1"
         aria-label="Tab 2"
     >Tab 1</a>
   </nav>
   <section
      id="panel-1"
      role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="tab-1"
      tabindex="0">Panel 1</section>
   <section
      id="panel-2"
      role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="tab-2"
      tabindex="0">Panel 2</section>
</section>
```

Worth mentioning:

- `display: none` to avoid loading of inactive contents (React.js)
- `tabindex`allows controlling tabs with the keyboard
- `href` can be used to keep state by direct link to a tab, but requires onClick event handler with `e.preventDefault()` to avoid page reload.
- `<section>` could be seen as only the whole and not as a content section, probably depends on what you show inside the panels.

ATM I will stick to my way but I will do some more investigation about this when time, as W3C seems to prefer `<button>`.

Ask yourself:

- Can everyone use it as intended?
- Did you provide accessibility support for the mentally/physically impaired?