# Next.js execute onClick event before href link routing

Tags: javascript, next.js, apollo-client

**Context**

I'm using Next.js 13. And I'm using apollo client to store some client side variables.

**What i'm trying to do**

I'm trying to execute the onClick function prior to navigating to the href location.

**My Code**

```
<Link
      href={`/session/${session.id}`}
      onClick={() => {            
        updateDialogVars({
          dialogOpen: ATTENDANCE_DIALOG,
        })
      }}
    >
    <div>
      stuff
    </div>
</Link>
```

updateDialogVars is a mutation and updates a reactive vars in apollo client.

**Question**

Is it possible to use Next.js Link component and execute the onClick event before routing takes place with the href? Is the only option to change Link to a div and use next router to push the route change after the onClick function executes?

Answer (score 3):

This is typically achieved with a button and [router hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), not an anchor tag (link).

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router"; // if you use pages dir
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"; // if you use app dir

const SomeComponent = () => {
 const router = useRouter();

 const onClick = async () => {
  updateDialogVars(...yourConfig);
  if(someCondition) {
   await router.push(`/session/${session.id}`);
  }
 }

 return (
  <button onClick={onClick}>Label</button>
 )
}
```

You can also achieve a similar result with next/link.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router"; // if you use pages dir
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"; // if you use app dir
import Link from "next/link";

const SomeComponent = () => {
 const router = useRouter();

 const onClick = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  updateDialogVars(...yourConfig);
  if(someCondition) {
   await router.push(event.target.href);
  }
 }

 return (
  <Link href={`/session/${session.id}`} onClick={onClick}>Label</Link>
 )
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to take advantage of the Next.js Link prefetch the page in the background. but if this is the only way to do it i guess that's alright

Comment: I updated the answer to use next/link

Comment: If you're rocking the app directory make sure to change the `useRouter` import path to `next/navigation`. See the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook

Comment: That's not semantic though, see [this answer to the question, "Why are buttons discouraged from navigation?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30937223/705296)